# How to caputure keyDown event in NSbutton after a mouseClick

Tags: macos, cocoa, keydown, nsbutton

I'm having five Image Buttons. If a button was clicked by mouse, then the button went to Onstate. Now if i pressed Space button it will zoom the button's image in a seperate Window.
The space button should not work when the button id in OFFstate. now can i trigger the Keyevent? i already referred Quicklook and working on that. any new ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to trigger the key event, just respond to it as though it were any old method call from the button.  After giving it a target and a selector, give it a key equivalent of `@" "` and respond to the key press accordingly:

```
- (void)someAction:(NSButton*)sender event:(NSEvent*)event {
    //...
    if ((sender.state == NSOnState) && (event.keyCode == 0x32)) {
        //Zoom
    }
    //...
}
```